# Content of ValidateUser method

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know the content of the Membership.ValidateUser(...) method in ASP.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/). Then add System.Web.dll and go to:

System.Web.Security Namespace -> SqlMembershipProvider Class -> ValidateUser Method

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I've been lookin for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Microsoft source code ProviderToolkitSamples.msi from here:

The method is in the SQLMembershipProvider.cs file.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about what you mean but here is the MSDN reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx

Hope that helps!